# Using jQuery to change value of one dropdown from another

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have 2 drop down lists and I would like to make it so that when someone selects for example value 2 from dropdown1, dropdown2 is automitacally changed to value 2.  Is this possible using jquery?

```
<select id="dropdown1">
 <option value="1">Item1</option>
 <option value="2">Item2</option>
 <option value="3">Item3</option>
</select>

<select id="dropdown2">
 <option value="1">Item1</option>
 <option value="2">Item2</option>
 <option value="3">Item3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Consider fixing the typo: `dropdWOn1` should be `dropdOWn1`

Comment: I made the change and it's waiting for approval...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$("#dropdwon1").change(function(){
    $("#dropdwon2").val($(this).val());
});
```

working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/xkT3U/

Comment: @hunter is it possible to make click on second drop down  after change event. I tried with  ** $("#dropdwon1").change(function(){
  
    
     $( "#dropdwon2" ).focus();
            $( "#dropdwon2" ).click();
});** but it didn't work .